# How do I namespace modernizr classes with js instead of with a custom build?

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

Modernizr allows for custom classname prefixes for the classnames it applies to the html (`supports-svg`, instead of `svg`). This can be configured in the custom build (extra -> className prefix), or with [grunt-modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/issues/47).

However, in my dev environment, I'm using the full (default) version from bower, so I can't configure it like I would with a custom build. Is there a way to tell modernizr what prefix to use with javascript? That way I could include a script after loading modernizr that tells it to use a `supports-` prefix for classnames.

---

*p.s.: I want to do this because I'm using html-inspector, and [by default it ignores `supports-*` classes, exactly for this purpose](https://github.com/philipwalton/html-inspector/blob/master/FAQs.md#how-can-i-get-html-inspector-to-stop-warning-me-about-unused-modernizr-classes). In my final build task I'm building modernizr with the `supports-*` prefix. But I can't do that for my dev. version, which is why I'm looking for a way to do the same with js.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to use a custom build if you want to customize it. I suggest checking out [grunt-modernizr](https://github.com/modernizr/grunt-modernizr)

Comment: "*I suggest checking out grunt-modernizr*". That is actually what I'm currently using. But it doesn't support adding all modernizr tests, which makes it an odd choice for a dev build. Which is why I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: "it doesn't support adding all modernizr tests" sure it does - what do you mean?

Comment: Well yeah technically it does, but I mean that you have to explicitly tell it to add each test you want to use, instead of having just an "all" switch.

Comment: Have you created an issue on the github requesting such a feature? shouldn't be hard to implement.

Comment: [There already is one](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/issues/53), but it's been there a while. I could just write a simple script that prefixes all classes on the html-tag with "supports-". It's a bit of a dirty fix, but it would work.